# Oracle error ora-19025 Xmltype

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g

I have imported a xml into oracle, i am using the column type Xmltype.

Here is the structure of the xml:

```
<Release>
<ReleaseId>
<GRid>A10320WA0003483489</GRid>
<ICPN IsEan="false">3610151317086</ICPN>
<CatalogNumber Namespace="UPC">3610151317086</CatalogNumber>
<ProprietaryId Namespace="ADAM_ID">551247405</ProprietaryId>
</ReleaseId>
<ReleaseReference>R551247405</ReleaseReference>
<ReferenceTitle>
<TitleText>Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco</TitleText>
</ReferenceTitle>
<ReleaseResourceReferenceList>
<ReleaseResourceReference>A551248137</ReleaseResourceReference>
<ReleaseResourceReference>A551248136</ReleaseResourceReference>
<ReleaseResourceReference>A551248070</ReleaseResourceReference>
<ReleaseResourceReference>A551248074</ReleaseResourceReference>
<ReleaseResourceReference>A551248041</ReleaseResourceReference>
<ReleaseResourceReference>A551247836</ReleaseResourceReference>
</ReleaseResourceReferenceList>
```

And here is the Select tha i am using

```
select extractvalue(value (sr),'*/ReleaseId/ISRC') as ISRC
      ,extractvalue( value (sr),'*/ReleaseId/GRid' )as GRid
      ,extractvalue( value (sr),'*/ReleaseId/ICPN' )as ICPN
      ,extractvalue( value (sr),'*/ReleaseId/CatalogNumber' )as CatalogNumber
      ,extractvalue( value (sr),'*/ReleaseId/ProprietaryId' )as ProprietaryId
      ,extractvalue( value (sr),'*/ReferenceTitle/TitleText' )as TitleText
      ,extractvalue( value (sr),'*/ReleaseType' )as ReleaseType
      ,extractvalue( value (st),'*/ReleaseResourceReference' )as teste
from xml_ddex x,
table(xmlsequence (extract(dados, '*/ContainedReleaseList/Release' )))sr,
table(xmlsequence(extract(value(sr),'*/ReleaseResourceReferenceList')))st
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: Jay, show me your expected result. I can't recognize what `dados` and `xml_ddex` is in your question.

Comment: ... and I need to know what are you trying to achieve. Clearly, the `teste`-aliased column is your problem, but that does not tell me what you need as the query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some guessed facts about your data and about your expected results, this might be the query you're after:

```
select --+ no_merge(SR)
    SR.isrc, SR.grid, SR.icpn, SR.catalog_number, SR.proprietary_id, SR.title_text, SR.release_type,
    ST.rel_res_ref as teste
from xml_ddex X
    cross join xmltable(
        '*/ContainedReleaseList/Release'
        passing X.dados
        columns
            rel_res_ref_list$       xmltype path '/Release/ReleaseResourceReferenceList',
            ISRC                    varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/ISRC',
            GRid                    varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/GRid',
            ICPN                    varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/ICPN',
            catalog_number          varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/CatalogNumber',
            proprietary_id          varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/ProprietaryId',
            title_text              varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReferenceTitle/TitleText',
            release_type            varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseType'
    ) SR
    cross join xmltable(
        '/ReleaseResourceReferenceList/ReleaseResourceReference'
        passing SR.rel_res_ref_list$
        columns
            rel_res_ref             varchar2(200) path '/ReleaseResourceReference'
    ) ST
;
```

I am sorry about the `no_merge` hint. In my test environment I just couldn't get the query to work without the hint; it was throwing `ORA-600` exceptions.

---

**A test on some partially guessed XML ...**

```
with xml_ddex as (
    select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" ?>
        <SomeRootElementIGuessThereIs>
            <ContainedReleaseList>
                <Release>
                    <ReleaseId>
                        <GRid>A10320WA0003483489</GRid>
                        <ICPN IsEan="false">3610151317086</ICPN>
                        <CatalogNumber Namespace="UPC">3610151317086</CatalogNumber>
                        <ProprietaryId Namespace="ADAM_ID">551247405</ProprietaryId>
                    </ReleaseId>
                    <ReleaseReference>R551247405</ReleaseReference>
                    <ReferenceTitle>
                        <TitleText>Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco</TitleText>
                    </ReferenceTitle>
                    <ReleaseResourceReferenceList>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248137</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248136</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248070</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248074</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248041</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551247836</ReleaseResourceReference>
                    </ReleaseResourceReferenceList>
                </Release>
                <Release>
                    <ReleaseId>
                        <GRid>A10320WA0003483489</GRid>
                        <ICPN IsEan="false">3610151317086</ICPN>
                        <CatalogNumber Namespace="UPC">3610151317086</CatalogNumber>
                        <ProprietaryId Namespace="ADAM_ID">551247405</ProprietaryId>
                    </ReleaseId>
                    <ReleaseReference>R551247405</ReleaseReference>
                    <ReferenceTitle>
                        <TitleText>Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno</TitleText>
                    </ReferenceTitle>
                    <ReleaseResourceReferenceList>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248137</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248136</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248070</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248074</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551248041</ReleaseResourceReference>
                        <ReleaseResourceReference>A551247836</ReleaseResourceReference>
                    </ReleaseResourceReferenceList>
                </Release>
            </ContainedReleaseList>
        </SomeRootElementIGuessThereIs>'
    ) as dados
    from dual
)
select --+ no_merge(SR)
    SR.isrc, SR.grid, SR.icpn, SR.catalog_number, SR.proprietary_id, SR.title_text, SR.release_type,
    ST.rel_res_ref as teste
from xml_ddex X
    cross join xmltable(
        '*/ContainedReleaseList/Release'
        passing X.dados
        columns
            rel_res_ref_list$       xmltype path '/Release/ReleaseResourceReferenceList',
            ISRC                    varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/ISRC',
            GRid                    varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/GRid',
            ICPN                    varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/ICPN',
            catalog_number          varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/CatalogNumber',
            proprietary_id          varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseId/ProprietaryId',
            title_text              varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReferenceTitle/TitleText',
            release_type            varchar2(200) path '/Release/ReleaseType'
    ) SR
    cross join xmltable(
        '/ReleaseResourceReferenceList/ReleaseResourceReference'
        passing SR.rel_res_ref_list$
        columns
            rel_res_ref                 varchar2(200) path '/ReleaseResourceReference'
    ) ST
;
```

... yields ...

```
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco       A551248137
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco       A551248136
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco       A551248070
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco       A551248074
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco       A551248041
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 101 Hits - I Left My Heart in San Francisco       A551247836
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno               A551248137
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno               A551248136
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno               A551248070
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno               A551248074
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno               A551248041
A10320WA0003483489  3610151317086   3610151317086   551247405   Tony Bennett: 102 Hits - I Left My Head in Fresno               A551247836
```